# TypeScript: type error on spread operator

Tags: typescript

Why is this not allowed?

```
type Key = 'aaa' | 'bbb' | 'ccc' | 'ddd'

type SomeObjectType = {
  key: Key
  isActive: boolean
}

const list: SomeObjectType[] = [
  { key: 'aaa', isActive: true },
  { key: 'bbb', isActive: false },
  ...(someBooleanValue
    ? [
        { key: 'ccc', isActive: false },  <-- error
        { key: 'ddd', isActive: false },  <-- error
      ]
    : []),
]
```

It shows an error on the objects with key: 'ccc' and 'ddd' saying...

```
(property) key: string
Type '{ key: string; isActive: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'SomeObjectType'.
  Types of property 'key' are incompatible.ts(2322)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The inner array type gets widened - specifically, the key is seen as `string`, not `key`. Use `as const` so it doesn't get widened, so it can be seen as assignable to `SomeObjectType` when spread outside

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by CertainPerformance in his comments, you can use `as` keyword to explicitly tell the compiler mention that your array element is of `SomeObjectType` type.

The as keyword is a [Type Assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) in TypeScript which tells the compiler to consider the object as another type.

```
let list: SomeObjectType[] = [
  { key: 'aaa', isActive: true },
  { key: 'bbb', isActive: false },
  ...[{ key: 'ccc', isActive: false },{ key: 'ddd', isActive: false }]  as SomeObjectType []
]
```

Also, when you are using the Conditional (ternary) operator `? :` , you are spreading an empty array after `:` .

Instead, you can concat the array after the list has been initialized.

```
type Key = 'aaa' | 'bbb' | 'ccc' | 'ddd'

type SomeObjectType = {
  key: Key
  isActive: boolean
}
const someBooleanValue = true;

const arr: SomeObjectType[] = [{ key: 'ccc', isActive: false },{ key: 'ddd', isActive: false }]
let list: SomeObjectType[] = [
  { key: 'aaa', isActive: true },
  { key: 'bbb', isActive: false },
]
list = someBooleanValue ? [...list, ...arr] : list;
```